# UITableView tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: not getting called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios4

I have 3 table views in one view and I was wondering why the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` was not getting called.

```
 #pragma mark -
 #pragma mark <UITableViewDelegate>
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    if (tableView == self.mainVoucherTableViewController)
       [self setSelectedIndex:indexPath.row];
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
    if (tableView == self.mainVoucherTableViewController){
  return 10;
     }
 }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    if (tableView == self.mainVoucherTableViewController){
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"THISTEXT";
    return cell;
   }
}


 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

 if (tableView == self.mainVoucherTableViewController)
     return 1;
 }

 - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// The header for the section is the region name -- get this from the region at the section index.
if (tableView == self.mainVoucherTableViewController){
    NSString * myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HELLLO WORLD"];
    return myString;
  }
}
```

WOULD anyone know why this is? Basically this doesn't create any cell or display cells. It just displays the table views. :(

Comment: Check the connections between the table and its data source.

Comment: Are you using a `UITableViewController` or a `UIViewController`? If the latter is your tableview hooked up with your delegate and data source in IB?

Comment: Double check dataSource and delegate of your `UITableView`s are set, either by outlet linking or code.

Comment: I guess you are comparing a view with a controller in `tableView == self.mainVoucherTableViewController`?

Comment: @iBlue Well i am creating a UITableView by code within a UIViewController ,

Comment: @josh caswell - I dont have a datasource yet. I just want to see the tables appearing. and i am hardcoding data.

Comment: You have to have a data source. The object that implements this method (which is part of the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol) must be connected to the table view's `dataSource` outlet.

Answer (score 1):

Start off by logging inside your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to see if it gets called at all outside your if statement as well as inside to help narrow down the issue.

Also try instead of comparing your:

```
tableView == self.mainVoucherTableViewController
```

Set the tableViews to have tag values instead.  Then you can do:

```
if(tableView.tag == 100){ // tag number we assigned self.mainVoucherTableViewController via IB
    //do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to consolidate a few things from above:

1. From your naming, your tableView is called mainVoucherTableViewController - just want to confirm that this is indeed a UITableView and not a UITableViewController?  If it's a UITableViewController then the rest of this won't work for obvious reasons (or not so obvious - let me know and can explain further)
2. Make sure you have set the current viewController as the tableView's delegate and dataSource, either with the code below or in Interface Builder if you're using a XIB

   ```
   self.mainVoucherTableViewController.delegate = self;
   self.mainVoucherTableViewController.dataSource = self;
   ```
3. Make sure your numberOfRowsInSection function is being called and that you're returning non-zero (put in NSLogs, etc) and do the same for numberOfSections as well (actually numberOfSections isn't required if you're only using 1 section) - see UITableViewDataSource Protocol Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html
4. As per previous post, log your cellForRow (if points #1-3 are checked and working) at the beginning to make sure it's triggered, and just before the return.  Also do an NSLog of the cell you're returning just to make sure it isn't nil.

Comment: The problem is the Cellforrowatindexpath is nto getting called. So i cant log anything. I used the bebugger and its not even going into the method.

Comment: I have also done everything else that you've written there. And sorry maintableviewcontroller is actually a tableview and not a talbeviewcontroller

Comment: Are you able to either send me your code or post the entire contents of the .m and .h files here?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
     if (tableView == self.mainVoucherTableViewController)
    {
       return 10;
     }
      else
     {retun 5;
     }
   }
```

It display row in first table 10, second table show 5 rows.

Answer (score -1):

The order of instance declaration does matter. For example, if you have a ivar called `tableView`:

**WRONG**

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView = [UITableView alloc] init];
```

**CORRECT**

```
self.tableView = [UITableView alloc] init];
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score -1):

check UITableView Object Frame Size. maybe Frame size is not enough to draw Cell.